# Integration with EPIC Interconnect web service

Tags: epic

1. To secure the communication channel, does EPIC interconnect web service (especially personal management API) supports WS-Security?
2. To make channel secure between caller and Interconnect web service, the only solution is HTTPS and PKI (public key infrastructure) authentication. Is this a correct statement?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation? Could you provide links to show some of your research?

Comment: Links https://open.epic.com/Interface/WebServices and https://open.epic.com/Operational/PersonnelManagement gives no or very little information on how to secure the channel between caller and EPIC interconnect service.

Comment: The PersonnelManagement SOAP API provided by Epic systems does not include an Authorization layer ("auth-z" in security slang) in the protocol.  This means there is no username and password exchanged between SOAP clients (Caller) and the SOAP server (Epic).